# Debugging webpack/browserify React app in IntelliJ/WebStorm

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm

I followed almost all guides I found online and I can not make debugger in IntelliJ stop at breakpoints.

I am developing React app with router. Backend is in Play Framework.

I tried generating source map using. This is from gulpFiles:

```
var bundler = watchify(browserify('./frontend/app.jsx', { debug: true }).transform(babel, {
        presets: ["es2015","react","stage-3"],
        plugins: [
            "transform-decorators-legacy",
            "transform-runtime"
        ]
    }));
```

Source maps were generated; I was able to debug in Chrome debugger but I am not able in IntelliJ. I only see console output.

I tried generating with webpack:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/javascripts');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend');

var config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                loader : 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "source-map"

};

module.exports = config;
```

Same thing I can not stop at breakpoints in IntelliJ.

I configured JavaScript debug like this:

```
Name: React Debug
URL: http://localhost:9000/index
Remote URLs of local files (optional) : ./frontend
```

Still no luck and breakpoints are not working. What am I missing??

Comment: "Remote URLs of local files" is obviously wrong - it should be web URL, not a path in file system

Comment: see also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-react-apps/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with Webpack.
I was using npm task to run webpack and instead of :

```
webpack -d --watch
```

as was suggested everywhere. I used this:

```
webpack --debug --output-pathinfo --watch
```